# implementing globbing in a shell prototype

Tags: c, bash, shell

I'm implementing a linux shell for my weekend assignment and I am having some problems implementing wilcard matching as a feature in shell. As we all know, shells are a complete language by themselves, e.g. bash, ksh, etc. I don't need to implement the complete features like control structures, jobs etc. But how to implement the `*`?

A quick analysis gives you the following result:

```
echo *
```

lists all the files in the current directory. Is this the only logical manifestation of the shell? I mean, not considering the language-specific features of bash, is this what a shell does, internally? Replace a `*` with all the files in the current directory matching the pattern?

Also I have heard about Perl Compatible Regular Expression , but it seems to complex to use a third party library.

Any suggestions, links, etc.? I will try to look at the source code as well, for bash.

Comment: Those are not regular expressions, but rather wildcards. E.g. `*` is not a valid regular expression since `*` is a *qualifier*. Also this is called [globbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) (a form of pattern matching).

Comment: "wild cards" . tomatoes tometoes , that's what I meant , wild cards .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's what shell does. It will replace `'*'` characters by all files and folder names in `cwd`. It is in fact very basic regular expressions supporting only `'?'` and `'*'` and matching with file and folder names in `cwd`.
Remark that backslashed `\*` and `'*'` enclosed between simple or double quotes `'` or `"` are not replaced (backslash and quotes are removed before passing to the command executed).

Comment: It's called globbing. It's not a form of regular expressions.

Answer (score 3):

This is called "globbing" and the function performing this is named the same: [glob(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/glob)

Answer (score 1):

If you want more control than [`glob`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/glob.html) gives, the standard function [`fnmatch`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fnmatch.html) performs just glob matching.

Note that shells also performs word expansion (e.g. `"~"` → `"/home/user"`), which should be done before glob expansion, if you're doing filename matching manually.  (Or use [`wordexp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/wordexp.html).)

Comment: Thanks but I guess I'm gonna go with writing my own function for wildcard matching .